# TFLearn regression loss function is uninitialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I'm messing around trying to replicate the tflearn autencoder listed [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/autoencoder.py) in a Kaggle Kernel.  The invocation looks like this:

```
class AutoEncoder():
    def __init__(self, layers):
        """layers should be a list of layer sizes"""
        self.layers = layers
        self.encoder = None
        self.decoder = None
        self.decoding_model = None
        self.encoding_model = None

    def fit(self, X):
        # build encoder
        self.encoder = [tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, X.shape[1]])]
        for layer in self.layers:
            self.encoder.append(tflearn.fully_connected(self.encoder[-1], layer))

        # build decoder
        self.decoder = [self.encoder[-1]]
        for layer in reversed(self.layers[:-1]):
            self.decoder.append(tflearn.fully_connected(self.decoder[-1], layer))
        self.decoder.append(tflearn.fully_connected(self.decoder[-1], X.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))

        # regression
        net = tflearn.regression(self.decoder[-1], 
                                 optimizer='adam', 
                                 learning_rate=0.001, 
                                 # loss='mean_square',
                                 loss='weighted_crossentropy',
                                 metric=None)
        self.decoding_model = tflearn.DNN(net)

        #encoding
        self.encoding_model = tflearn.DNN(self.encoder[-1], session=self.decoding_model.session)



        self.decoding_model.fit(X, X, n_epoch=20, batch_size=256)
        return self.decoding_model

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.encoding_model.predict(X)

ae = AutoEncoder([1024, 256, 2])
ae.fit(X_train)
```

However, upon running, it fails with an error that indicates my loss function has not been initialized:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1291     try:
-> 1292       return fn(*args)
   1293     except errors.OpError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1276       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1277           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1278 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1366         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1367         run_metadata)
   1368 

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value WeightedCrossentropy/Mean/moving_avg_1
     [[{{node WeightedCrossentropy/Mean/moving_avg_1/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Adam_1/moving_avg/AssignMovingAvg"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](WeightedCrossentropy/Mean/moving_avg_1)]]
```

With TFLearn, I am not quite sure where the correct place is for global variable initialization, or if that would even solve the problem.  Could someone please advise with why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to fix this particular error. Move `fit` before the previous line.

```
    self.decoding_model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    self.decoding_model.fit(X, X, n_epoch=20, batch_size=256)

    #encoding
    self.encoding_model = tflearn.DNN(self.encoder[-1], session=self.decoding_model.session)
```